# PHPMyAdmin Error #1064 when migrating Wordpress Site

Tags: mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I am trying to move my Wordpress website from `Hostgator` to `iPage` host.

Normally, this is a relatively easy process, but this time it has an error.  I never used `iPage` before, so it might be something to do with that.  I have no idea of the issue right now, could it be something to do with different `phpMyAdmin` version?  the `iPage` host interface seems a bit older to me.

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server
version for the right syntax to use near 'order, tag ) VALUES ( 1, 1, 'Master', NULL, NULL, '<?php 
\n\necho the_title(); \' at line 1
```

Any help on how to fix this issue would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: its because order is a reserved key word and its failing, you will need to wrap it within backtics.

Comment: How did you make your SQL dump? And how are you trying to import it?